# function to remove red in an image using python module image

Tags: python, image, colors, rgb

I am trying to trying to teach myself python from the net. Have no previous prg experience. need help on how to write a function to remove red from an imgae using the 'image' module in python. The code i tried to write is below ...do help

```
import image

img = image.Image("luther.jpg")

newimg = image.EmptyImage(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight())

win = image.ImageWin()

def no_red():
    for col in range(img.getWidth()):
        for row in range(img.getHeight()):
            p = img.getPixel(col,row)
            newred = 0
            newgreen = p.getGreen()
            newblue = p.getBlue()
            newpixel = image.Pixel(newred,newgreen,newblue)
    return newimg.setPixel(col,row,newpixel)



print (newimg.getPixel(45,52))
win.exitonclick()
```

what am i doing wrong? Any guidance will be helpful :)

Regards >>

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `newimg.setPixel` inside the `for` loops, otherwise it'll only replace one pixel all the way at the end of the image:

```
def no_red():
    for col in range(img.getWidth()):
        for row in range(img.getHeight()):
            p = img.getPixel(col,row)
            newred = 0
            newgreen = p.getGreen()
            newblue = p.getBlue()
            newpixel = image.Pixel(newred,newgreen,newblue)
            newimg.setPixel(col,row,newpixel)
```

You also aren't calling `no_red` anywhere. I recommend writing something like this instead:

```
def no_red(image):
    new_image = ... # make a copy of image
    # original code that removes red subpixels
    return new_image
```

And then calling:

```
new_image = no_red(original_image)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(img.getWidth()):
        for j in range(img.getHeight()):
            old_pixel = img.getPixel(i, j)
            new_pixel = image.Pixel(0, old_pixel.getGreen(), old_pixel.getBlue())
            new_image.setPixel(i, j, new_pixel)
```

This is the simplest way to do it in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get stuck with the loops, you may find the following lines more useful. The following lines removes RED from the image test.

```
def removeColour():
        img =  Image.open('test.png').convert('RGB')
        source = img.split()
        R, G, B = 0, 1, 2
        out = source[R].point(lambda i: i * 0)
        source[R].paste(out, None, None)
        img = Image.merge(img.mode, source)
        img.save('testNoRed.png')
        img.show()
```